# Stored Procedure works fine except insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I am trying to perform few insert and updates in a stored procedure but it isn't working accordingly. Everything works fine except insert statements. I am unable to figure out the problem.

My stored procedure is as below

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_Return_Sample_SubmitForApproval]                                        
 @Receipt_Id INT,                
 @Remarks NVARCHAR(2000),                  
 @Label nvarchar(250),                        
 @User_Remarks nvarchar(2000),                        
 @Status char(1),                                
 @User_Id INT,                                
 @Role_Id INT,                          
 @Unit_Id INT,                          
 @Unit_Type_id INT,          
 @Analyst_Id  INT,      
 @ParamXML   XML                                
AS                                                
BEGIN                                                
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from                                                
-- interfering with SELECT statements.                                                
 SET NOCOUNT ON;                                      
 Declare @intErrorCode INT, @Project_Id INT, @Sample_Type NVARCHAR(100) ,@InventoryCount INT, @UpdatedCount INT                         

 BEGIN TRAN       
  DECLARE @tv_Doc TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,ReceiptId INT,SampleTypeId INT,StorageId INT,RackId  INT, ShelfId  INT,Box_Id INT,Project_Id INT,Matrix_Type_Id INT )                  

  INSERT INTO @tv_Doc (ReceiptId,SampleTypeId,StorageId,RackId,ShelfId,Box_Id,Project_Id,Matrix_Type_Id )                                   
  SELECT          
  TempDoc.Item.value('@RecieptId', 'INT'),           
  TempDoc.Item.value('@SampleTypeId', 'INT'),            
  TempDoc.Item.value('@StorageId', 'INT'),                               
  TempDoc.Item.value('@RackId', 'INT'),                    
  TempDoc.Item.value('@ShelfId', 'INT'),    
  TempDoc.Item.value('@Box_Id', 'INT'),    
  TempDoc.Item.value('@Project_Id', 'INT'),    
  TempDoc.Item.value('@Matrix_Type','INT')                   
  FROM @ParamXML.nodes('/root/row') AS TempDoc(Item)    




  UPDATE [ITEMS] SET [ITEMS].Instrument_Id = [TEMP].StorageId, [ITEMS].Rack_Id = [TEMP].RackId,[ITEMS].Shelf_Id = [TEMP].ShelfId,[ITEMS].Box_Id =[TEMP].Box_Id            
  FROM BSMS_CPP_RCPT_RETURN_ITEMS [ITEMS] INNER JOIN BSMS_CPP_INVENTORY [INV] ON [ITEMS].Item_Barcode = [INV].Item_Barcode     
  INNER JOIN @tv_Doc [TEMP] ON [ITEMS].Sample_Type_Id  = [TEMP].SampleTypeId AND [ITEMS].Receipt_Id = [TEMP].ReceiptId AND [INV].Box_Id =  [TEMP].Box_Id    
  AND [TEMP].Project_Id = [ITEMS].Project_Id   AND ([TEMP].Matrix_Type_Id = 0 OR [TEMP].Matrix_Type_Id = [ITEMS].Matrix_Type_Id)    

  UPDATE BSMS_CPP_RCPT_RETURN SET Status = @Status,Remarks =@Remarks, Created_Datetime=GETDATE()  WHERE Receipt_Id = @Receipt_Id             

  IF (@Status = 'V')            
  BEGIN    

  UPDATE [INV] SET [INV].Storage_Type_Id=[TEMP].StorageId,[INV].Rack_Id=[TEMP].RackId,[INV].Shelf_Id=[TEMP].ShelfId    
  FROM BSMS_CPP_INVENTORY [INV] INNER JOIN @tv_Doc [TEMP] ON [INV].Category_Id  = [TEMP].SampleTypeId AND [INV].Box_Id =  [TEMP].Box_Id    
  AND [INV].Project_Id = [TEMP].Project_Id    AND ([TEMP].Matrix_Type_Id = 0 OR [TEMP].Matrix_Type_Id = [INV].Matrix_Type_Id)        


  UPDATE [INV] SET [INV].Is_Exist = 1,[INV].Storage_Type_Id=[ITEMS].Instrument_Id,[INV].Rack_Id=[ITEMS].Rack_Id,[INV].Shelf_Id=[ITEMS].Shelf_Id            
  ,Replaced_By=@User_Id,Replaced_Analyst =@Analyst_Id ,Replaced_Datetime=GETDATE()--,Category_Id = [ITEMS].Sample_Type_Id    
  FROM BSMS_CPP_INVENTORY [INV] INNER JOIN BSMS_CPP_RCPT_RETURN_ITEMS [ITEMS] ON [INV].Item_Barcode = [ITEMS].Item_Barcode    
  INNER JOIN @tv_Doc [TEMP] ON [ITEMS].Sample_Type_Id  = [TEMP].SampleTypeId AND [ITEMS].Receipt_Id = [TEMP].ReceiptId AND [INV].Box_Id =  [TEMP].Box_Id    
  AND [TEMP].Project_Id = [ITEMS].Project_Id   AND ([TEMP].Matrix_Type_Id = 0 OR [TEMP].Matrix_Type_Id = [INV].Matrix_Type_Id)           
  WHERE [ITEMS].Receipt_Id = @Receipt_Id            

  DELETE FROM BSMS_CPP_INVENTORY_ANALYST WHERE BSMS_CPP_INVENTORY_ANALYST.Item_Barcode IN            
  (SELECT [ITEM].Item_Barcode FROM BSMS_CPP_RCPT_RETURN_ITEMS [ITEM] WHERE [ITEM].Receipt_Id = @Receipt_Id)    

   DECLARE @Dt DATETIME = GETDATE()   
  INSERT INTO BSMS_CPP_RCPT_RETURN_ESIGN                 
  (Receipt_Id,User_Role,User_Id,User_Datetime,User_Remarks,Action_Label)VALUES                        
  (@Receipt_Id,@Role_Id,@User_Id,@Dt,@User_Remarks,@Label)         

  INSERT INTO BSMS_CPP_RCPT_RETURN_ESIGN                 
  (Receipt_Id,User_Role,User_Id,User_Datetime,User_Remarks,Action_Label)VALUES                        
  (@Receipt_Id,@Role_Id,@Analyst_Id,@Dt,@User_Remarks,'Witnessed By')                           


   EXEC USP_AT_INS_CPP_Return_Sample @Receipt_Id, @Dt              


   DECLARE @Replaced_FRC NVARCHAR(200),@Replaced_Analyst NVARCHAR(200)    
   SELECT @Replaced_FRC = Display_Name FROM BSMS_MST_SYS_USERS WHERE User_Id = @User_Id    
   SELECT @Replaced_Analyst = Display_Name FROM BSMS_MST_SYS_USERS WHERE User_Id = @Analyst_Id    

   UPDATE [ISSUE] SET Replaced_Samples = '1', Replaced_FRC=@Replaced_FRC,Replaced_Analyst =@Replaced_Analyst ,Replaced_Datetime=@Dt,Remarks = @Remarks    
  FROM BSMS_RPT_ISSUANCE [ISSUE] INNER JOIN BSMS_CPP_INVENTORY [INV] ON [ISSUE].Inventory_Id = [INV].Inventory_Id    
  INNER JOIN BSMS_CPP_RCPT_RETURN_ITEMS [ITEMS] ON [INV].Item_Barcode = [ITEMS].Item_Barcode    
  WHERE [ITEMS].Receipt_Id = @Receipt_Id AND [ISSUE].RPT_Receipt_Id = (SELECT MAX([ISS].RPT_Receipt_Id) FROM BSMS_RPT_ISSUANCE [ISS] WHERE [ISS].Inventory_Id = [INV].Inventory_Id)     

  END            



  SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR                                    

  IF (@intErrorCode <> 0)                                     
  ROLLBACK TRAN                                    
  COMMIT TRAN                                    
  Select @intErrorCode [ERROR]                                        
END
```

In above procedure below insert statements doesn't insert data into table.

```
DECLARE @Dt DATETIME = GETDATE()   
  INSERT INTO BSMS_CPP_RCPT_RETURN_ESIGN                 
  (Receipt_Id,User_Role,User_Id,User_Datetime,User_Remarks,Action_Label)VALUES                        
  (@Receipt_Id,@Role_Id,@User_Id,@Dt,@User_Remarks,@Label)         

  INSERT INTO BSMS_CPP_RCPT_RETURN_ESIGN                 
  (Receipt_Id,User_Role,User_Id,User_Datetime,User_Remarks,Action_Label)VALUES                        
  (@Receipt_Id,@Role_Id,@Analyst_Id,@Dt,@User_Remarks,'Witnessed By')
```

Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: MySql and SQL Server? Which is it?

Comment: @Larnu I am using SQL server 2005.

Comment: why you have used ID  column as identity column. this is causing the issue.

Comment: @AmitKumar I have updated my question. i am having problem in those statements which insert data in other tables. Thanks.

Comment: and the errormessage is ?

Comment: @GuidoG Nothing, it just doesn't insert value into BSMS_CPP_RCPT_RETURN_ESIGN and that too sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Id` column to have values of `RecieptId` which you are providing in your insert statement then there is no point in having the `Id` column as `Identity` column.

An Identity column automatically increments the column counter for every new record inserted.

So for your insert to work, either remove `@RecieptId` from your inserted values
and `Reciept_Id` from the columns to be inserted.

or if you want to explicitly insert Reciept_Id then

do not mention it in the create table definition like this

```
DECLARE @tv_Doc TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL,ReceiptId INT,SampleTypeId INT,StorageId INT,
RackId  INT, ShelfId  INT,Box_Id INT,Project_Id INT,Matrix_Type_Id INT )
```

Comment: I have updated my question. I think @tvdoc doesn't have any relation with other two inert statements. Thanks for pointing my mistake. Please help with other one too.

Comment: I think this answer is right, the thing is you can't insert values when a field is tagged as IDENTITY, because it means only the DB engine can write to that field. You'll have to drop the column and recreate it, or tweak your script so it creates the table without the identity definition.